# How do you configure MySQL to run on localhost port 3306?

Tags: mysql, localhost

A number of Java/MySQL tutorials, such as [one by Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html), assume that MySQL is somehow running in the background on your machine, and you need to connect to it. The problem is, that there seem to be no easily available documentation on precisely how to get the MySQL in that state.

When I try connecting to it, I get all sorts of errors.

I get this error when I type `mysql` into the Command Prompt:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

And this error when I run the Java code from Vogella's site:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:356)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2502)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at MySQLPractice.readDataBase(MySQLPractice.java:17)
    at MainSQL.main(MainSQL.java:4)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:258)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: The problem here is with starting your MySQL server, not with your code.

Comment: Maybe use google, with keywords "install" "mysql" and the name of your operating system

Comment: It's not meant to be a negative comment, I'm just pointing out that that huge error message is not relavant. What did you do to set up MySQL?

Comment: @ChrisLear I installed it properly. The question is, how to get it running in localhost

Comment: @AnubianNoob I downloaded the web-community `msi` from [Oracle](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/)

Comment: Assuming ubuntu/debian linux, try apt-get install mysql-server

Comment: @ChrisLear He installed it, and can't get it set up.

Comment: bind-address        = 127.0.0.1 in /etc/mysql/my.cnf. Oh, windows... then look for where it puts my.conf, and edit that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install mysql server, not just the client!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port number in the MySQL config file: my.cnf you can locate this file in 
 /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: Except that he's using windows, so maybe C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y\my.ini

Comment: completely agree i suggest him to read documentation related to windows

Comment: @ChrisLear I don't have a folder inside `MySQL` called `MySQL Server`.  I have a bunch of others though: `MySQL Workbench`, `MySQL Utilities`, `MySQL ForExcel`, among many

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-file-location.html This will help you

Comment: Maybe you've installed mysql client, but not mysql server. Make sure you have the right download. You can install the client on its own, but that will be no use to you without the server

Comment: please check the document  it says config files is in my.ini and locate the file either at c:\my.cnf or c:\Windows\my.ini.

Comment: @ChrisLear Yes you are right, that's what happened. It wasn't clear that I had to install the server, it seemed like I only needed to download the database

Comment: I've added an answer now, which you can accept if you like :)